# How to build just one package using catkin_make?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I build just one package using catkin_make? I now that I can cd to the build directory and build there but that is inconvenient. And how do I build one package and its dependencies?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54178/how-to-build-just-one-package-using-catkin_make?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Build a single package including it's dependencies

```
catkin_make --only-pkg-with-deps <target_package>
```

Don't forget to switch back to building all packages when you are done

```
catkin_make -DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES=""
```

Description

Whitelists only the specified packages and their dependencies by setting the CATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES variable. This variable is stored in CMakeCache.txt and will persist between CMake calls unless explicitly cleared. Source: `catkin_make --help`

**But there is an even better way**

Using [Catkin-Tools](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html):

```
sudo apt-get install python-catkin-tools
```

Build specific package

```
catkin build <target_package>
```

Build the package from a directory under the package root

```
catkin build --this
```

Advantages:

- you can call `catkin build` from everywhere
- always builds packages seperately
- `catkin clean` cleans everything (instead of the dangerous `rm -rf build devel`)
- [more infos](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html)

Important notes for catkin_tools:

- You can't mix `catkin build` and `catkin_make` (delete your build/devel/install folders to switch tools)
- As `catkin_build` builds all packages seperately there can be problems when passing information between packages via CMake. [More Information](https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/83)

**Old answer for legacy reasons**

```
catkin_make --pkg <my_package_name>
```

Example:

```
catkin_make --pkg turtlebot
```

Multiple Packages:

```
catkin_make --pkg <package A> <package B>
```

But as this doesn't work robustly I recommend switching to [catkin_tools](http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which allows to build only one package and many more fancy features:

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2013-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 66

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-09-04**:
You can also use `--from-pkg <package>` to skip to that package and then continue building the workspace after that.

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2013-11-22**:
Is there any reason why I run this option and it keeps compiling everything within the catkin workspace?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-11-22**:
Which option? If you mean the `--from-pkg <package>` option, if you specify the first package in the workspace then it will build them all. The idea is that it skips all packages which come before the one you specify, but builds that one package and all packages that follow it.

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-01-07**:
I personally feel this is an important thing that ought to to be mentioned in the tutorials.

**Comment by [korkor](https://answers.ros.org/users/22243/korkor/) on 2015-05-05**:
I have the same problem as Javi V: I try to use this to make 1 package but it makes all the packages in the catkin_ws

edit: today it worked for reasons I don't understand.

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2017-03-10**:
I also occasionally try to use this trick and it rarely works. It just builds all of the packages still. I also can't tab complete my package.

**Comment by [burakaksoy](https://answers.ros.org/users/38717/burakaksoy/) on 2018-11-26**:
It did not worked for me either. catkin_make -DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES="foo;bar" command worked.

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-08-05**:
How is this an accepted answer? It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Tommy,

you can configure(!) a catkin workspace to only build one package using -DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES

```
# "List of ';' separated packages to build"
catkin_make -DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES="foo;bar"
```

This should really be documented in the docs and wiki.
If you want to build more packages, you'd have to reconfigure.

Other than that, catkin relies on cmake, which generates targets named like the subfolders. So calling catkin_make  (or make  in a build folder) will make just this target, and all target it depends on.

Finally you can use catkin_build_isolated, which really invokes cmake+make for each package. It creates isolated build folders in which you can invoke make. If you#d like to suggest for catkin to provide for this in another way(such as an option to place the isolated build folders within the packagefolders, feel free to open an enhancement ticket on github.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 17

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-04**:
Should `catkin_make PACKAGE` work, because for me it seems to do nothing?

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-02-04**:
I also have tested "catkin_make PACKAGE" and thought that that would work but it does not. That I could use "catkin_make TARGET" was not something I though about testing since I did not think it would work because of name collisions between targets. But it did work and can be very useful.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-04**:
Wait, did it work for you or not?

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-02-04**:
No it does not. But e.g. "catkin_make mpinfo" were mpinfo is a target in the package lrs_quad works.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-04**:
Doesn't work for me either. I'm not sure if it should. I don't want to hijack your question, so I described the problem here: http://answers.ros.org/question/54215/should-catkin_make-work-for-package-targets/ - the solution might be related though.

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2018-02-22**:
This solution worked for me:
`catkin_make -DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES=foo;bar`

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-02-23**:
`catkin_make -DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES="foo;bar"` works fine but be aware that you will have to run  `catkin_make -DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES=""` to be able to build all your packages again.
Also `catkin_make -DCATKIN_BLACKLIST_PACKAGES="foo;bar"` can be useful not to build some packages.

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-06-05**:
Hi Delb, thanks for that extra comment about building all packages again. The same thing may be said about blacklisted packages ( if you have a blacklisted package, just setting whitelisted = "" doesn't work... you will need to set blacklisted="" as well,, or remove it from blacklisted list somehow)

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-08-05**:
This must be the accepted answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The aforementioned answers are incorrect, `--pkg` still includes all packages as documented [here](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg/issues/71) which means if some untargeted package have unmet dependencies, the build will fail.

CATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGE does not correctly build dependent packages of the whitelisted package

The proper way is `catkin_make --only-pkg-with-deps <target_package>`

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2019-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bakerhillpins](https://answers.ros.org/users/40635/bakerhillpins/) on 2019-06-21**:
This command worked for me. The currently selected answer, `catkin_make --pkg <package A>` did not, as others noted it built all packages.